# Makefile evaluation, includes and loads

Tags: makefile, gnu

Say I have a Makefile called Bar like this in the directory A with is on the include path for Make.

```
load ./foo.so
```

And I have another Makefile in the directory B.

```
include Bar
```

The include is succeeding, but its a dump copy paste rather than what I want. I want the load in `Bar` to go off, then when I do include its as if I had the functions that foo.so provides to be available.

I also tried this in file Bar

```
path := ${shell pwd}/foo.so

load ${path}
```

But this didn't work either because the pwd it gets is from within directory B but I wanted it to be in directory A.

Comment: `load` is not a Make function, `load ./foo.so` is not valid Make syntax, and if `foo.so` is a shared object library then what do you expect Make to do with the functions it contains? My guess is that you want `foo.so` to be available to the linker in commands, but if so then this is the wrong approach. Is that what you're trying to do? And is `A` one of the default inclusion directories, or did you add it?

Comment: Have you tried load ./foo.so. It is valid make syntax, https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/load-Directive.html and I did solve my problem, albeit with symlinks.

Comment: I stand corrected. I am unfamiliar with this feature, though in my defense it is listed as a “technology preview” extension.

Comment: Which directory do you call `make` command from? How A and B directory relate to each other? Is A a child of B?

Comment: A, B are completely unrelated directories. I call make from B directory.